# Making the challenge presented by Google invisible reCAPTCHA reactive

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recaptcha, reactive, invisible-recaptcha

When google's invisible reCAPTCHA can't ascertain whether or not you are a bot, you are presented with a challenge (the tile selection challenge, to be precise). My issue is that google's reCAPTCHA is not responsive, so it does not fit on screen when presented on mobile, or when the webpage is resized.

The resizing solutions posted for previous versions of reCAPTCHA mess with the 'g-recaptcha' css selector, but this doesn't seem to apply to the challenge presented by the invisible version. In the case of invisible reCAPTCHA, the g-recaptcha selector only seems to apply to the badge.

If it matters, I'm using javascript/react